# Finding the Average of a Column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, overflow, average

I am attempting to find the average for all of the numbers in a given column.

```
'Find the Average

Dim count As Integer
Dim sum As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim num As Long
lastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.count).Column
For c = 2 To lastCol
   sum = 0
   count = 0
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, c).Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        sum = sum + ActiveCell.Value
        count = count + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop
    'num = sum / count
    ActiveCell.Value = sum / count
    'ActiveCell.Value = num
```

When I try and run this, I receive an overflow error for the line

```
 ActiveCell.Value = sum / count
```

I have tried many different ways to get around this problem. One solution I tried was using an intermediate long variable "num" in this case to pass the value. That attempt at a solution is commented out above. Another solution I tried was using CLng() to typecast the variables into a long. Both of these solutions still produced the same overflow error. Does anyone have any idea as to how to fix this problem?

Comment: What types of numbers do you have - all whole numbers, some real numbers (1.051...) and do you only want a whole number as your answer?

Comment: Are you really only summing whole numbers between   −32,768 and 32,767? What are the values of `sum` and `count` when you hover over them in debug mode?

Comment: Chips - I have both whole numbers and real numbers and I would like to keep them a real numbers

Comment: Jeeped - When I enter debug mode, the sum and count inside the loop are both 0's

Comment: I did try changing the count variable to a double, but received the same overflow error.

Comment: It is possible that it does, therefore it would be outside the range of an int, but I don't know how else to go about it. Converting the variables to a long and a double did not solve the problem

Comment: So setting sum and count to 0 outside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way to get the average of all the cells in the last column of a worksheet, excluding the first row:

```
Sub Luxation()
   Dim lastCol As Long, rng As Range
   lastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
   Set rng = Range(Cells(2, lastCol), Cells(Rows.Count, lastCol))
   MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
End Sub
```